# TwitterOAuth.php will not run 'use'

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth, php-5.6

Error is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/includes/display-functions.php on line 9

```
require_once "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;    //<--this is line 9 where the error occurs

$consumerkey = '***************';
$consumersecret = '*********************************************';
$accesstoken = '*********************************************';
$accesstokensecret = '******************************';

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret ,$accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$statues = $connection->get("statuses/home_timeline", array("count" => 25, "exclude_replies" => true));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your PHP version ?

Comment: I guess you'll have to show the first 8 lines of that document because there is nothing obviously wrong here and your php version is high enough for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have just stumbled on this.

I haven't been able to figure out why it wasn't working but managed a simple workaround.

This is the working code:

```
require_once "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
//use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;    //<--this is line 9 where the error occurs

$consumerkey = '***************';
$consumersecret = '*********************************************';
$accesstoken = '*********************************************';
$accesstokensecret = '******************************';

$connection = new Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret ,$accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
```

Hope it might be of help to anyone.